# JMX invoke with Deployer get an InstanceNotFoundException

Tags: java, jmx

We have a JMX application where we open the connection, then use object name `Catalina:type=Deployer,host=[hostname]` in method invoke (to check if the application is deployed) but we get an exception (InstanceNotFoundException).  What can be the cause of this?

Comment: Please show some of your code.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to be helpful here without seeing more the code or context.  However, if you look at the [javadocs for `MBeanServerConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServerConnection.html) which backs most of the JMX clients, you can see that `InstanceNotFoundException` means:

> InstanceNotFoundException The MBean specified is not registered in the MBean server.

This means that the `ObjectName` that you specified does not match a bean name registered with the JMX server that you are connected to.

The `ObjectName` that is used must match *exactly* the one registered by the server.  The same name should have been returned using a call to:

```
Set<ObjectName> names = mBeanServerConnection.queryNames(null, null);
```